# KML file - Create a linestring with different color?

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [colorise single track in kml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874858/colorise-single-track-in-kml-file)

I wanted to create a linestring with different parts of line having different colors.
I am using google-earth API to load the kml files.

If I can achieve this goal by doing google-earth javascript programming, that would also be fine. But I would prefer if I can achieve this in kml file.

One easy way that I can think of is to create multiple lines with different colors. When I load this kml file to Google Earth, it looks like a path. This makes the size of file bigger and takes long time to load the file. So looking for a better way.

Comment: I don't think that's possible via JS or KML, you have to create a polygon (which will make the closed shape) and then draw the colored segments over top the line segments polygon. It can all be done in one KML, you just need two parts. Without the bottom "enclosing" polygon it will look like a path.